# Dynamically add or remove text fields and insert into a single row

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to Add or Remove input fields and insert data into a single row in a table and **my problem is after generating input fields I can't insert every fields data into a single row**

My data is inserted in a separated row.

Please watch my code. Especially php code ( Line no 10 in **name.php** )

[**Please Click here and watch my html codes**](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwxzcDIDrRP-QzloN1d4S084azg)

[**Please Click here and watch my php codes**](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwxzcDIDrRP-bTlXYkN6bXRIcTA)

Comment: Add your code here instead of linking it. Also its not clear what are you trying to achieve? Its good if you give an example

Comment: I was stored my codes on Google Drive . Here are the links ** HTML CODE:-
 https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwxzcDIDrRP-QzloN1d4S084azg **  PHP CODE:-
 https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwxzcDIDrRP-bTlXYkN6bXRIcTA

Comment: SO is not a free consulting service. Please put your code in the question. It must be minimal to highlight the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

this code replace in name.php file.

```
<?php
 extract($_POST);
 $name=implode(",",$_POST['name'])
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");

 $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_name(name) VALUES('".$name."')";

 mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

 ?>
```

Comment: I was tried this and now my new php code is `$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");  $number = count($_POST["name"]);  $number = implode(",",$_POST["name"]); if($number > 0) {  for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++){if(trim($_POST["name"][$i] != '')){ $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_name(name)VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["name"])."')";                mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
 } } echo "Data Inserted"; } else { echo "Please Enter Name"; }`      but it's showing   **mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in**

Comment: bro your code is working . Data were inserted https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwxzcDIDrRP-MktTWmVweFZEMUE  but give me solution when I want to fetch this **name** field and show every data separately then ??????????? **Please give this code**

Comment: <?php echo $row['name']; ?>

    all data is fetch you insert in field.

first try to fetch ... if problem in fetch so tell me i'm ready for give solution.

Comment: but I want to echo data separately (Eg: 1    2    3   4   5   6   7) but if I normally fetch data and then it's showing 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

Comment: If i fetch and echo **name** field then it's showing 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 but I just want to select and echo Number 4 and 6 . This is the problem

Comment: If you need Please watch sql database stored data https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwxzcDIDrRP-MktTWmVweFZEMUE

Comment: If i fetch and echo name field then it's showing 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 but I just want to select and echo Number 4 and 6 . This is the problem . If you need Please watch sql database stored data drive.google.com/open?id=0BwxzcDIDrRP-MktTWmVweFZEMUE

Comment: you want to only 4 and 6 number??

Comment: In the name field I have stored this data **1,2,3,4,5,6,7** (for more clear info please watch my database https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwxzcDIDrRP-MktTWmVweFZEMUE/view)    **and now please understand my problem:-- I just want to fetch and echo 4 and 6** So I want code

Comment: `<?php 
   
    $name=exlode(",",$row['name']); 
    for($i=0;$i<=count($name);$i++)
    {
        if($name[$i]==4 || $name[$i]==6)
        {
             echo $name[$i];
        }
    }


?>`

Comment: bro I trying using your codes . If I will want your support then I will contact you later .

Comment: I have a separate php problem problem please give support . Please check my problem:- 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44859714/php-mysqli-data-cant-properly-echo-after-fetching-from-database